# I have factory reset my phone, there is almost a gb of app installation space

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, insufficient-memory

My 16gb SD Card got corrupted today, so I lost all of my data as I was unable to format it.

The real problem is, I also factory reset my phone just now, so there is 16gb internal memory amd 1.5gb app installation memory, out of which only 400mb is used.

When I attempt a download from Google Play Store, they get downloaded completely however while installing, it gives an error message "Insufficient storage". I'm fed up with this issue, I don't know what to do.

Let me also tell you, my SD Card data was encrypted, so I was unable to format it, should this be a problem. However, I factory reset my phone and now internal memory can do nothing with it.

My phone is [Intex Aqua Power HD](http://www.fonearena.com/intex-aqua-power-hd_6277.html) running Android 4.4

Comment: One more addotion, just now i tried to download other apps like coc, n stackoberfloe, these got installed quickly. So i tried to install.my whatsapp again n again it gave sameerror message insufficient storage.

Comment: I uninstalled those previous two apps, jist to empty the innapp space aain n tried to download whatsapp n aain it gave same error, i have all d space in d app memory, as there is nothing installed. Im getting this error only with whatsapp installation

Comment: Pleas include your comments in your question. You can always edit your own question.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, try to connect your SD Card to another device and Format/copy out your important files.

If that does not work, use a card reader to access your SD Card on a [Windows](http://www.phonereviewng.com/) device and SCAN as appropriate.

It could well be a minor threat and your PC anti-virus could solve.

Comment: What has an anti-virus got to do with anything?